# two sql tables having 197000 rows in word table and second is wp_posts contains 60000 rows want to subtract second second table from first?

Tags: sql, wordpress

i have many searched on google for this from last 3 days got many solution but not efficient works for small databases ;

like below

```
 SELECT title FROM word o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM wp_posts c
WHERE c.post_title = o.title)
```

Please provide me an efficient solution so that searching becomes fast just like dictionary websites.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT` syntax, so I use `LEFT JOIN` here:

```
SELECT title
FROM word o

/* try joining a wp_post based on title */
LEFT JOIN wp_posts c
       ON c.post_title = o.title

/* LEFT JOIN couldn't join anything? Good for us: */
WHERE c.ID IS NULL /* you can use any NOT NULL field here, not just ID */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT    title 
FROM      word 

EXCEPT

SELECT    post_title 
FROM      wp_posts
```

If that works depends on the DBMS you are using, though...

Answer (score 0):

You should check the join, might be it can help you

```
SELECT title FROM word o 
INNER JOIN wp_posts wp
ON p.title <> wp.post_title
```

Comment: That joins all records in word with all records in wp_posts that have a different title... Does something completely different than the original query (and is SLOW!).